# How to reference a xslt stored in your project folder on as asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have my xslt's stored in a folder in my asp.net web application project folder.

Is there anyway i can call this style sheet from an asp.net web page?

Answer (score 1):

```
var fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Details.xsl")

File.ReadAllText(fullPath)
```

VB .Net

```
Dim fullPath = HttContext.Server.MapPath("~/Details.xsl")

File.ReadAllText(fullPath)
```

Comment: I seem to get an issue with File.ReadAllText(fullPath) as it just returns the whol xml document, rather than the result of having the xslt applied to it.

Comment: This is a totally another issue. Look for "apply xslt to xml with .Net". You still need to read the Details.xsl file/